# What does ‘Move the bar on somebody’ mean?

Tags: phrases

According to Maureen Dawd’s article titled “Field of Dashed Dream’ appearing on August 16 New York Times, President Obama took a strong verbal punch on the chin from a woman supporter at a town hall meeting at the Seed Savers Exchange in Iowa. 
She asked the President "what had gone wrong" with him, and continued:

> “So when you ran for office you built a tremendous amount of trust with the American people, that you seemed like someone who wouldn’t *move the bar on us*. ---
>   And it seems as if your negotiating tactics have sort of cut away at that trust by compromising some key principles that we believed in, like repealing the tax cut, not fighting harder for single-payer. Even Social Security and Medicare seemed on the line when we were dealing with the debt ceiling.”

I don’t understand what ‘*move the bar on somebody’* mean. I checked the meaning of this phrase on the Google, but couldn’t find out any definition.

Comment: Possibly related to "move the goalposts", with the meaning "We thought we knew your objectives, but they've changed". But I'm not certain, because it's a usage which is new to me.

Comment: Agreed. Normally, you *raise the bar* and *move the goalposts.* But if you get confused, you might *move the bar* and *raise the goalposts.*

Comment: @PeterTaylor Similar. To "move the goalposts" is a football metaphor meaning to unfairly make the target something other than what's expected. To "raise the bar" is a similar metaphor from high-jump, with the subtle difference that raising the bar is a legal part of the sport, and thus has less of the "unfair" connotation. In this example, I think they're aiming for the idea of unfairness or underhandedness, so as Peter Shor suggests, they've mixed their metaphors and should have used "move the goalposts".

Answer (score 6):

I think that the woman is coining metaphors based on the phrase, *raise the bar*. To [*raise the bar*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38231/what-does-move-the-bar-on-somebody-mean) means:

> to set a higher standard for other people to follow

So, if you raise the bar you are raising standards--the "bar" is a metaphor for those standards. To then say that someone is *moving* the bar implies that someone is shifting the standards around, and not necessarily for the better.

The woman is saying that, when Obama was elected, he promised to stand by X standards. Now, however, he has *moved the bar* on people and is now standing by Y standards. In other words, he is being weasely and not sticking by the standards he set.

I don't think this is standard English, so I wouldn't use it in conversation.

**Edit:** @Phoenix brings up the related metaphor [*moving the goalposts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts) which is more common. It means:

> changing the target of a process or competition by one side in order to gain advantage.

Unlike *moving the bar on us*, which may be more regional, this phrase seems a lot more common. A quick [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=moving+the+bar+on%2Cmoving+the+goalposts&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) yields:

[image]

You could definitely use this phrase in conversation to describe this situation, and it is possible that because it is more common you would be more widely understood.

Comment: ＠Simchona. Thank you very much for your quick answer. I guessed ‘move the bar’ means ‘move one’s stand or change the standards,’ but got confused with adjunct ‘on us.’

Comment: @Yoichi: I think the woman felt that by moving the bar, they were being betrayed in some sense--thus "on us", as if the action was taken against them.

Comment: I've heard the phrase all my life here in Georgia.  And yes, it does mean pretty much exactly what you said, usually with negative connotations.  Usually it's something like someone sets a requirement to do something, then when you fulfill the requirement, they add on more requirements.  Like, what's that old greek myth, where the guy wants to marry the king's daughter and the king says you have to go and kill such and such horrible monster thinking that he'll die in the attempt, but then he succeeds, so the king gives him another test, and he succeeds, and then another test, etc.

Comment: @Phoenix: Interesting--I couldn't find that use online either, but I'm glad I got it pretty much right. Thank you for providing some more context to the phrase. (And do you mean Hercules?)

Comment: No, it's not Hercules, he was told upfront that there would be a number of trials for him to atone for his crimes.  I just can't remember the guy's name, I usually have an encyclopedic memory for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Phoenix I think this is getting off topic for this thread. But if you think of it, come find me in EL&U chat.

Comment: Can't find any reference to it now, might be mistaken, might not even be Greek myth, but it was certainly myth of some sort.  I also just thought of something, "Moving the goalposts" would probably be a more common saying that means much the same as "moving the bar".

Comment: @Phoenix I hope you don't mind, but I added the other metaphor to my answer.

Comment: @Phoenix.Given your comment, ‘Move the bar’ reminds me of Japanese popular saying, ‘Expand Sumo ring,’ where you are required to wrestle within the definite circle line. If you expand or change the line, i.e., the diameter of ring, there is no fair bout.

Comment: @Peter Taylor. Following the above comment, it appears to me that our ‘‘Expand the Sumo ring (circle line)’ resembles ‘Move the bar,’ and different from ‘Raise the bar’ suggested by @ Bohemian. For me ‘Move the bar’ seems to mean ‘moves the goalpost, i.e., ‘change promise, rules’ as suggested by Peter Taylor. While ‘Raise the bar’ means ‘make the condition harder or chance for success less,’ the woman seems to have accused the President Obama of changing his platforms (moving the bar), rather than raising his standards (raising the bar). This is just a non-native English learner’s view.

Comment: "The NFL (professional American football) kept the [goal]post at the goal line until 1974, when they were _moved back_ to the rear of the end zone." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_goal (emphasis added) The spike in the Ngram just a few years after this event seems like more than a coincidence to me.

Answer (score 4):

It's a misspoken version of "raise the bar", which originates from the high jump competition of athletics, when the "bar is raised" to the next height, making it harder to clear. In broader usage, "raising the bar" means that the minimum required standards in the context have been increased.

Comment: Yes, to the reference to  field sports: high jump (and pole vault. And yes to the notion of "nor

Answer (score 1):

It's a conflation of "raise the bar" and "move the goalposts" -- both idioms from (sports metaphor) for changing the goal, generally to make the challenge harder.

"Raise the bar" has a connotation of fairness: the bar is raised as part of the larger contest as people succeed at the old way; akin to an old record being broken, so now people are trying to break the new record. ("Raise the bar" is often said of the person who achieved greatness by the old standard, and thus set the new standard.)

"Move the goalposts" (or goal line) has a connotation of unfairness: the goal was set, attempts were begun, and before they could be played out, the standards by which the outcome would be judged was changed.

In this case, I believe the speaker meant something more like the latter.

Comment: The Ngram in the answer by @simchona shows a spike in the early 1980s. It seems highly likely that this is because in American football, the professional league literally moved the goalposts farther back. "The NFL kept the post at the goal line until 1974, when they were moved back to the rear of the end zone." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_goal